# Handling outdated browsers

Tags: php, laravel, redirect, laravel-4, cross-browser

I have laravel 4.1.31 and added a filter for outdatedBrowsers. If the user agent is specific to the old versions then it renders a page returns Out Dated Brower.

BUT

[Moz](https://moz.com/) reports a **Pages with Temporary Redirect** issue. Is there anyway to prevent this either by server config or from better laravel code handling?

Your responses appreciates a lot, thanks!

Comment: You should describe the issue a little better. It's hard to understand the problem at the moment.

Comment: What i miss? 

Let me rephrase, there are many old browser versions people are using. I want them NOT to enter my laravel web app due to incompatibilities. 

Now what i am doing is using middleware concept to prevent these kind of user-agents (the client device).

Is there any other good way to do? MOZ tracking redirect issues if i filter/middleware them

Answer (score 0):

Change `/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php/asset()` function as follows (just example):

```
function asset($path, $secure = null)
{
    return app('url')->asset("public/".$path, $secure);
}
```